# Remove dynamically added elements from HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having issue removing dynamically added attributes from HTML. There is a parent component(not controlled by me) which has a click functionality where it calls an API and adds a HTML element to the DOM.  Now i have to remove this element from DOM when the click functionality is done and HTML is rendered. I tried below two methods, but did not had luck as the element is unavailable

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  const ele = document.getElementById("remEle");
  console.log(ele)

})

$(document).ready( function() {
      const ele = document.getElementById("remEle");
      console.log(ele)

})


<div id="container">
  <div class="header-class" id="remEle">
    "Header"
     <div class="item-class">item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In both the cases i am getting "ele" as undefined and not able to remove it.

Comment: What does the html look like? Also, you have a typo: `addEventListner` should be `addEventListener`.

Comment: If the element loads on the click event, then the load event would not be appropriate for removing it; the element doesn't exist yet when loading. Perhaps you can add another listener to the click event to remove it.

Comment: updated HTML and corrected the typo.  As i mentioned the code for click event is not in my control, Is there any way i can alter this on my side with element information?

Comment: Do these elements get dynamically loaded? Or are they present in the HTML file?

Comment: @Josh they are dynamically loaded on click there is an ajax call and receiving response the elements will be added.

Comment: You should be able to add another listener to the click event that loads the element. *Maybe* use `setTimeout()` to give the ajax time to do its thing.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You need to wait for the element to exist. I use this script when I have that need: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-wait-for-element-to-exist

Comment: You can use a `MutationObserver` to execute code when the element is created.